# 'str' object is not callable even not used str in code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

i am getting this error. how to solve this? please help me out.

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd
import csv

# Load csv
#df = pd.read_csv("D:\Harsha\Trading\cm14SEP2018bhav.csv")

# Read in csv file
#for row in csv.reader(open("D:\Harsha\Trading\cm14SEP2018bhav.csv"), delimiter=','):
      #print(row)
#import csv

infile = 'H:\cm09NOV2018bhav.csv'
outfile = 'H:\output_cm09NOV2018bhav.csv'

wfh = open (outfile, 'w')

with open(infile, 'r') as fh:

    reader = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=',')
    wfh.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{}".format("SYMBOL", "OPEN", "HIGH", "LOW", "CLOSE", "ISIN", "TOTTRDQTY", "STATUS"))
    wfh.write("\n")
    for row in reader:
        symbol = row['SYMBOL']
        series = row['SERIES']
        open = row['OPEN']
        high = row['HIGH']
        low = row['LOW']
        close = row['CLOSE']
        last = row['LAST']
        prevclose = row['PREVCLOSE']
        tottrdqty = row['TOTTRDQTY']
        tottrdval = row['TOTTRDVAL']
        timestamp = row['TIMESTAMP']
        totaltrades = row['TOTALTRADES']
        isin = row['ISIN']
        print(low.rstrip())
        if float(high.rstrip()) in [9,25,49,81,121,169,225,289,301,441,529,625]:
            wfh.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(symbol, open, high, low, close, isin, tottrdqty, "SELL"))
            wfh.write("\n")
        elif float(low.rstrip()) in [9,25,49,81,121,169,225,289,301,441,529,625]:
            wfh.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(symbol, open, high, low, close, isin, tottrdqty, "BUY"))
            wfh.write("\n")
        elif float(close.rstrip()) in [9,25,49,81,121,169,225,289,301,441,529,625]:
            wfh.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(symbol, open, high, low, close, isin, tottrdqty, "CLOSE PRICE"))
            wfh.write("\n")
        elif float(open.rstrip()) in [9,25,49,81,121,169,225,289,301,441,529,625]:
            wfh.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(symbol, open, high, low, close, isin, tottrdqty, "OPEN PRICE"))
            wfh.write("\n")

#wfh._archive.close()
wfh.close()
```

I have not used str in my code. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: I don't think that can be your complete code; for me, python throws a syntax error just trying to compile it, and ending with `with open(infile, 'r') as fh:` looks wrong;  please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Begging and SHOUTING instead of reading comments and improving your question does not help.  Format the code to be readable and post the error message.  Most likey at some point you've done `str = 'something'` and overridden the default value of `str`.  Restart your editor.

Comment: Mark i am not shouting on anybody nor i am begging. I am seeking guidance from seniors to solve this str callable error. I have not included str anywhere in my whole code. Then why i am getting this error?

Comment: @kamalsharma the way this error is normally produced is if you do something like this: `a = 'hello'; print(a());` - if you assign a `str` type object to a variable and then try to 'call' that object as if it were a function. you have used plenty of strings in this code, but I don't see anything that would cause this error. It is also possible if you overwrite a built in function (or one of your own functions) with a string object, then try to call it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **when you're using format to print, you should avoid adding a string value to the format argument**.

so all the code that's writing to the wfh file like these:

`wfh.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(symbol, open, high, low, close, isin, tottrdqty, "SELL"))`

need to be changed to:

```
wfh.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},SELL".format(symbol, open, high, low, close, isin, tottrdqty))
# here 'Sell' is a part of the print argument which is already under quotes.
```

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
        open = row['OPEN']
```

this code re-assigns the python keyword open (which you use to open files) with the contents of `row['OPEN']` that means that now when you call `open` you are calling a `str` object, not a function.

consider this:

```
print(type(open))
# <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
open = 'hello, world'
print(type(open))
# print(type('hello, world'))
```

you can no longer 'call' open (ie `open('file.txt', 'r')`) because it is a string, not a function.